# Quantum mechanics: Can you simplify $\langle x\rangle\langle p\rangle$ further?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-states

Really quick question: It feels somehow wrong to write it out, so just correct me:
$$\langle x\rangle\langle p\rangle=\langle\psi|x|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|p|\psi\rangle =\langle\psi|xp|\psi\rangle=\langle xp\rangle.$$
The critical point probably consist of taking use of $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi| = 1$, which might not be valid.

Comment: Why do you think that $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|=1$ (where I assume that with $1$ you mean the identity operator)?

Comment: This is not valid.

Comment: But what about the completeness relation?

Comment: @Leon you should use the @ username function to notify another user. The completeness relation is something different in general and the difference is obvious if you compare both expressions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly,
$$|\psi \rangle \langle \psi |\neq 1 \tag{1}$$
in general. The operator (1) will project a state onto the $|\psi\rangle$ state.

Another way that you can see that your manipulation is wrong is it implies that $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ commute, which we know to not be true (to see this consider the fact that $\langle x \rangle \langle p \rangle = \langle p \rangle \langle x \rangle$ and then do the same manipulations you did above).

I don't think you could simplify this general form simpler than is useful.